# Robot framework doesn't see environment variable selenium_jar

Tags: macos, selenium, environment-variables, robotframework

i'm using mac

while using a pybot test.txt command i get an error msg: No executable path given, please add one to Environment Variable 'SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR'

but

i downloaded this jar from selenium site and did such things, nothing worked out:

added this folder path to /etc/paths;
added variable to etc/launchd.conf; 
setenv SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR /Users/User/Downloads/SeleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone.jar
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/User/Downloads/SeleniumServer/;

after all of this i tried i run pybot test.txt and receiving the same error message.

Please, help, i just don't know how to configure robot framework to work with safari.

Comment: Have you rebooted? If you open a terminal and type "echo $SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR", does it show the value you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, i rebooted,and yes, if i type echo $SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR it shows me a path to a folder containing needed jar file

Comment: You say in the question that you set SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR to the jar file, in your comments you say it is set to the "path to a folder containing needed jar file" . Which is it? It needs to be set to the full path to the jar file, not the path to the folder.

Comment: I see, i changed it to a needed jar file, and it's worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response to comments, it appears you set SELENIUM_JAR_FILE to the wrong value. It needs to be set to the full path of the jar file, not just the folder that contains the jar file.